# Python transactions help needed for master-detail table insertion

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, transactions, python-requests

I am trying to implement Python Flask rest API. I have two tables (master-detail) in order to insert values from a parsed response of another rest API.

Here are my master-detail tables;

```
sql_create_purchase_confirmation_response_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase_confirmation (
                                        id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                        responseDatetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
                                        applicationCode text NOT NULL,
                                        version text NOT NULL,
                                        referenceId text NOT NULL,
                                        paymentId text NOT NULL,
                                        productCode text NOT NULL,
                                        quantity integer NOT NULL,
                                        currency text NOT NULL,
                                        unitPrice integer NOT NULL,
                                        totalPrice integer NOT NULL,
                                        merchantProductCode text NOT NULL,
                                        signature text NOT NULL,
                                        purchaseStatusCode text NOT NULL,
                                        purchaseStatusDate DATETIME NOT NULL                                        
                                        ); """

sql_create_purchase_confirmation_detail_response_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase_confirmation_detail (
                                            referenceId text NOT NULL,
                                            serials text NULL,
                                            pins text NULL
                                            ); """
```

And here is my functions to insert into tables separately.

```
def add_purchase_confirmation_response(database_file, response):
query = "INSERT INTO purchase_confirmation (responseDatetime, applicationCode, version, referenceId," \
        "paymentId, productCode, quantity, currency, unitPrice, totalPrice, merchantProductCode," \
        "purchaseStatusCode, purchaseStatusDate, signature) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

con = ''
try:

    with sql.connect(database_file, isolation_level=None) as con:
        con.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query, [str(datetime.now()),
                            response['applicationCode'], response['version'], response['referenceId'],
                            response['paymentId'], response['productCode'], response['quantity'],
                            response['currency'], response['unitPrice'], response['totalPrice'],
                            response['merchantProductCode'], response['purchaseStatusCode'],
                            response['purchaseStatusDate'], response['signature']])

        con.commit()

except sql as e:
    con.rollback()
    print e.message
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise

finally:
    con.close()

def add_purchase_confirmation_detail_response(database_file, response):
query = "INSERT INTO purchase_confirmation ( referenceId," \
        "serials, pins) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

con = ''
try:

    pins = ''
    # parse response coupons
    for item in response['coupons']:
        for itemS in item['serials']:
            serials = itemS

            for itemP in item['pins']:
                pins = pins + itemP + ','

            print serials.rstrip(',')
            print pins.rstrip(',')

            # insert into table here
            with sql.connect(database_file, isolation_level=None) as con:
                con.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal')
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute(query, [response['referenceId'], serials, pins])

                con.commit()
            pins = ''

except sql as e:
    con.rollback()
    print e.message
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise

finally:
    con.close()
```

**In order to provide data consistency, is there a way to use transaction? I am new to Python, I would be glad if you can guide me. **

```
def confirmation():
try:
    uri = 'https://teststore.com/purchaseconfirmation'
    r = requests.post(uri, data=request_params_confirmation)

    add_purchase_confirmation_response('test.db', r.json())
    add_purchase_confirmation_detail_response('test.db', r.json())
    return jsonify(r.text)
except Exception as e:
    return e.message
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has "atomic" transactions if you use [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). Probably in `confirmation` function, call a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` query before add_purchase... calls and then execute a `commit` or `rollback` depending on success or failure. You may also find this doc on [busy timeout](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) salient.

Comment: Should I remove commits 'con.commit()' inside of purchase calls?

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that. If you want to treat the two inserts as one transaction, they need to be "wrapped" as one transaction.